# Jenkins pipeline Warnings Next Generation Plugin: git rev-parse HEAD^{commit} takes a (too) long time

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

This is the relevant part of the `Jenkinsfile`:

```
stage('Static Code Analysis') {
    options {
        timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS')
    }
    steps {
        withMaven(jdk: "${JDK_VERSION}", maven: 'M3', mavenLocalRepo: '.repository') {
            sh 'mvn --no-transfer-progress verify --activate-profiles qa -Dpmd.analysisCache=true'
        }
        recordIssues(tools: [
                checkStyle(),
                pmdParser(),
                spotBugs(useRankAsPriority: true)
        ])
        dependencyCheckPublisher pattern: 'target/dependency-check-report.xml'
    }
}
```

This is an excerpt from the Jenkins console log:

```
00:10:26.471  [CheckStyle] Successfully parsed file /home/ubuntu/jenkins/workspace/iText_7_Java_itextcore_develop/target/checkstyle-result.xml
00:10:26.471  [CheckStyle] -> found 0 issues (skipped 0 duplicates)
00:10:26.847  using credential bd100583-6d56-496a-89c0-67e640c2f80e
00:10:27.322  using credential bd100583-6d56-496a-89c0-67e640c2f80e
00:10:26.896   > /usr/bin/git rev-parse HEAD^{commit} # timeout=10
00:10:27.699  using credential bd100583-6d56-496a-89c0-67e640c2f80e
00:10:28.173  using credential bd100583-6d56-496a-89c0-67e640c2f80e
00:10:27.748   > /usr/bin/git rev-parse HEAD^{commit} # timeout=10
00:12:10.218   > /usr/bin/git rev-parse HEAD^{commit} # timeout=10
00:25:35.352  [CheckStyle] Post processing issues on 'jenkins-node-aws' with source code encoding 'UTF-8'
00:25:35.352  [CheckStyle] Creating SCM blamer to obtain author and commit information for affected files
00:25:35.352  [CheckStyle] -> Git blamer successfully created in working tree '/home/ubuntu/jenkins/workspace/iText_7_Java_itextcore_develop'
00:25:35.352  [CheckStyle] Creating SCM miner to obtain statistics for affected repository files
00:25:35.352  [CheckStyle] -> Git miner successfully created in working tree '/home/ubuntu/jenkins/workspace/iText_7_Java_itextcore_develop'
00:25:35.352  [CheckStyle] Resolving file names for all issues in source directory '/home/ubuntu/jenkins/workspace/iText_7_Java_itextcore_develop'
00:25:35.352  [CheckStyle] -> resolved paths in source directory (1238 found, 0 not found)
00:25:35.352  [CheckStyle] Resolving module names from module definitions (build.xml, pom.xml, or Manifest.mf files)
00:25:35.352  [CheckStyle] -> resolved module names for 85004 issues
00:25:35.352  [CheckStyle] Resolving package names (or namespaces) by parsing the affected files
00:25:35.352  [CheckStyle] -> resolved package names of 1238 affected files
00:25:35.352  [CheckStyle] No filter has been set, publishing all 85004 issues
00:25:35.352  [CheckStyle] Creating fingerprints for all affected code blocks to track issues over different builds
00:25:35.352  [CheckStyle] -> created fingerprints for 85004 issues (skipped 0 issues)
00:25:35.352  [CheckStyle] Invoking Git blamer to create author and commit information for 1238 affected files
00:25:35.352  [CheckStyle] GIT_COMMIT env = 'HEAD'
00:25:35.352  [CheckStyle] Git commit ID = '62d4a2abfda51f58acac8f4ce8e799dffcdbfb0a'
00:25:35.352  [CheckStyle] Git working tree = '/home/ubuntu/jenkins/workspace/iText_7_Java_itextcore_develop'
00:25:35.352  [CheckStyle] -> blamed authors of issues in 1238 files
00:25:35.352  [CheckStyle] Blaming of authors took 498 seconds
00:25:35.352  [CheckStyle] Analyzing the commit log of the Git repository '/home/ubuntu/jenkins/workspace/iText_7_Java_itextcore_develop'
00:25:35.352  [CheckStyle] Invoking Git miner to create statistics for all available files
00:25:35.352  [CheckStyle] Git working tree = '/home/ubuntu/jenkins/workspace/iText_7_Java_itextcore_develop'
00:25:35.352  [CheckStyle] -> created statistics for 1238 files
00:25:35.352  [CheckStyle] -> created report for 1238 files in 69 seconds
00:25:35.352  [CheckStyle] Copying affected files to Jenkins' build folder '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/iText_7_Java/jobs/itextcore/branches/develop/builds/910/files-with-issues'
00:25:35.352  [CheckStyle] -> 1238 copied, 0 not in workspace, 0 not-found, 0 with I/O error
00:28:49.752  [CheckStyle] Using reference build 'iText_7_Java/itextcore/develop #909' to compute new, fixed, and outstanding issues
00:28:49.752  [CheckStyle] Issues delta (vs. reference build): outstanding: 85002, new: 2, fixed: 2
00:28:49.752  [CheckStyle] No quality gates have been set - skipping
00:28:49.752  [CheckStyle] Health report is disabled - skipping
00:28:49.752  [CheckStyle] Created analysis result for 85004 issues (found 2 new issues, fixed 2 issues)
00:28:49.752  [CheckStyle] Attaching ResultAction with ID 'checkstyle' to run 'iText_7_Java/itextcore/develop #910'.
```

Notice the jump in time stamp from `00:10:27.748` to `00:12:10.218` to `00:25:35.352`.
I see a similar (although less extreme) jump in time stamps when Jenkins is doing the `recordIssues` for PMD and SpotBugs.

This takes too long for just running `git rev-parse` and the delay is unacceptable. 13 minutes of doing absolutely nothing useful. No other jobs were running at the time. What is going on here and how to fix it?

EDIT:

The delay is *NOT*, and I repeat: ***NOT*** in the `mvn` command. It is in the `recordIssues` command.

EDIT:

- It is not just with Checkstyle
- It is also with PMD and Spotbugs

EDIT:

`recordIssues` is a Jenkins pipeline build step that comes from **Warnings Next Generation Plugin**.
https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/warnings-ng/#recordissues-record-compiler-warnings-and-static-analysis-results

Comment: Is this a network file system or an especially slow disk?  Is this system using antivirus software or something else that examines files that are opened?  What operating system are you running this on?  Do things change if you remove the `--no-transfer-progress` flag on `mvn`?

Comment: You can set the `GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE` environment variable to `true` to have more details on what steps take so long ; but it looks like a slooow filesystem issue as bk2204 suggested

Comment: @bk2204 this particular machine is an AWS EC2 t2.large instance with a 60 GiB gp2 volume. Amazon hardware is standardized, so does that give you enough information? The operating system is Ubuntu, 18.04 LTS, amd64 bionic, no antivirus.

Comment: I'll do the `GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE` thing later, during office hours, and edit my question with the result.

Comment: I have added `GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE = true` to the `environment` section of the `Jenkinsfile` and it doesn't make any difference. Does `recordIssues` use Git or JGit, and does JGit take environment variables into account?

Comment: The delay you're seeing isn't Git.  It's likely Maven or something else.  If you remove the `--no-transfer-progress`, you'll probably see output from Maven to tell you more about the problem.

Comment: Okay I have undone the `GIT_TRACE_PERFORMANCE` and now there's a branch running with `--no-transfer-progress` removed.

Comment: As expected, removing `--no-transfer-progress` does not make any difference. That is for two reasons, and I will explain them to you. First of all, `--no-transfer-progress` only hides the progress of downloading Maven artifacts. We're not in that phase at all. Secondly, the Maven command has already completed, and we are already in the `recordIssues` command. So any change to the `mvn` command is irrelevant.

Comment: @bk2204 does that answer your questions or do you need more information?

Comment: I don't know what it is, but there's definitely something going on which your `checkStyle` process that's causing the delay, maybe because it's reading a lot of files.  It's definitely not Git that's the cause of your problem here, but since I don't know what `checkStyle` does, I can't comment further.

Comment: It's not just Checkstyle. As I already wrote, in the question, but you may not have read it, it is also with PMD and Spotbugs. I have just edited my question to mention it again for the second time.

Comment: Any solution on this ? I am facing the same problem - recordIssues is taking 2-3 hours, to parse a 200 line file. The weird thing is that it is happening only on timer triggered Jenkins jobs, but not on Github triggered jobs(PRs, merges to master etc)

Comment: No solution, and I no longer work there, so I am not looking for a solution any more. I hope someone else can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this will qualify as an answer but I'm seeing this issue as well and it is, I believe, related to network transfer to the slave.

There is a significant upload that occurs when using the Warnings-NG plugin recordIssues step. I've examined what's changing on the filesystem when this transfer is happening (i.e. when recordIssues appears to be doing nothing) and the only files I see changing are in the Jenkins jarCache folder.

My theory is that the plugin is sending across jar files to cache for local execution on the slave node vs executing on the master. This likely works well when the slave is persistent, not so much when ephemeral.

Also, if I keep my slave node around for a subsequent build the issue goes away; likely because the cache is already populated.

Comment: Interesting. Indeed we always throw away the entire workspace after a build. Which is a waste of time imho, but some believe in "better safe than sorry". I don't experience the issue any more, because I have removed the `recordIssues` step. The only place where we see those issues now, is in SonarQube.

Comment: Yeah, my guess is anything using a remote executor and has a large library of parsers is going to send all of that over to the remote for local execution so Sonar likely suffers the same issue.